# Query Builder raw sub query is not working

Tags: sql, laravel, builder

I'm having Problem running this code.It says:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
> syntax.

I don't know if this is coming form `subquery`.Is it correct to write `subquery` like this?

```
    $result = DB::table('grievance_redress_info')
    ->select(
    'complainer_name',
    'phone',
    'complaint_date',
    'address',
    'complaintSub.name_en',
    'resolve_action_date',
    DB::raw("(SELECT grievance_history.status
    FROM grievance_history
    WHERE grievance_history.grievance_id=grievance_redress_info.id 
    ORDER BY grievance_history.id DESC LIMIT 1) AS current_status")
    )  
    ->leftJoin("common_labels AS 
    complaintSub",'grievance_redress_info.complaint_subject_id','=','complaintSub.id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this

```
$grievance_redress_info = DB::table('grievance_redress_info')
->select(
'complainer_name',
'phone',
'complaint_date',
'address',
'complaintSub.name_en',
'complaintMeans.name_en',
'resolve_action_date');
$result = DB::table('grievance_history')
    ->leftJoinSub($grievance_redress_info, 'grievance_redress_info', function ($join) {
        $join->on('grievance_history.grievance_id', '=', 'grievance_redress_info.id');
    })->select('grievance_history.status')->get();
```

you can check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#subquery-joins) for more

I hope this works!

Comment: but it is not working as expected.it is not returning result like raw subquery returned.

Comment: status is not returning

Comment: @RaffianMoin How about now?

Comment: still no luck.status is'nt there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233279/discussion-between-omar-esmaeel-and-raffianmoin).